# Aggregating full text fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to display the number of markets in an index. Each document has a field called market and I want aggregate the results like this:

> "Advertising and sales" : 400
>
> "Oil Industry" : 250
>
> "Metal Industry" : 125

I know how to display these results using the query:

```
"aggs":{
  "group_by_market":{
    "terms":{
      "field": "market"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when they are displayed; they don't get displayed correctly. The markets are displayed separately. For example:

> "Advertising": 400
>
> "Sales": 400
>
> "Oil": 322
>
> ...etc

How do I make it so the markets are aggregated with all the text?

Answer (score 0):

The type of your field is text. You need to specify mapping of the field as "keyword" field ( Elasticsearch version 5 + ) [Mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/string.html)

In older versions,mapping need to have "not_analyzed"   [Mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/string.html)

The basic difference between two is that one gets tokenized and meant for full text search while other one is meant for usecases like yours.

Comment: How do I specify mapping of the field as "keyword", what do I do in order to get the full text?

Comment: which version of ES you are using ?

Comment: I am using version 5.4

Comment: In that case , they are mapped to text and keyword fields by default . in your case, it will be mapped as group_by_market and group_by_market.keyword. so aggregating on "group_by_market.keyword" will give you results you need.

Comment: I'd suggest to read this doc -> https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings